# Vectorize loop of read.csv on filenames

Tags: r, vectorization, read.csv

I'm quite new to R, sorry if the programming looks bad.

Goal is to create filenames based on a common prefix, i.e. given prefix loop x times to produce prefix-1, prefix-2, prefix-3. And then use these filenames to read.csv(prefix-1,prefix-2, prefix-3).

I've gotten the code to work, but very inefficiently below:

```
name <- vector(mode="character", length=0)
for (i in 1:numruns)name[i] <- paste(prefix, "-", i, ".log", sep="")

if (numruns == 1) {
        raw_data_1 <-read.csv(name[1], header=F, sep="\t", skip=11)
}

if (numruns == 2) {
        raw_data_1 <-read.csv(name[1], header=F, sep="\t", skip=11)
        raw_data_2 <-read.csv(name[2], header=F, sep="\t", skip=11)
}

if (numruns == 3) {
        raw_data_1 <-read.csv(name[1], header=F, sep="\t", skip=11)
        raw_data_2 <-read.csv(name[2], header=F, sep="\t", skip=11)
        raw_data_3 <-read.csv(name[3], header=F, sep="\t", skip=11)     #import files
}
```

I'm trying to learn how to be more efficient, above works for my purposes but I feel like I should be able wrap it up in the initial loop that produces the names. When I try to modify the original loop I can't get it to work...

```
for (i in 1:numruns){
        name[i] <- paste(prefix, "-", i, ".log", sep="")
        raw_data <- paste("raw_data_", i, sep="")
        print(raw_data)
        raw_data <- read.csv(name[i], header=F, sep="\t", skip=11)
}
```

Rather than get raw_data_1,raw_data_2,raw_data_3... I get "raw_data". I'm confused because print(raw_data) actually prints "raw_data_1-3" correctly (but only "raw_data" actually contains any information).

Thanks for any help or critique on my code to make it more efficient.

Comment: As @tonytonov says, [tag:vectorization] is the generic term for converting loops to vectorized code. Use that tag to label, search etc. any such questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should start using native vectorization early on. It may be confusing at first, but eventually you'll see all its' power and beauty. Notice that many base functions are vectorized, so that looping over arguments is often redundant (see `paste` usage below). Learn more about `apply` family, it is an essential tool right from the start (see `lapply` call).

Since reading multiple files is a common task, here's the chain I frequently use. We build all file names first according to a known pattern. Then we read them all at once, without any loops whatsoever. Finally, we may want to combine a list of files into a single data frame.

```
n <- 4
prefix <- 'some_prefix'
file_names <- paste0(prefix, '-', seq_len(n), '.log')
#[1] "some_prefix-1.log" "some_prefix-2.log" "some_prefix-3.log" "some_prefix-4.log"
# a list of data frames
df_list <- lapply(file_names, function(x) read.csv(x, head=F, sep='\t', skip=11))
# total data frame (if all data frames are compatible)
df_total <- do.call(cbind, df_list)
```

Comment: This is great information! Thanks for taking the time to post this for me. I've struggled a bit to understand use of apply, as well as using functions in general. I think in the long run something that doesn't rely on loops makes a lot more sense as well. Thanks so much for the answer.

Comment: I caught myself doing what I started to in the OP. Naturally I was excited to use your above technique. However, instead of using read.csv, I'm using a custom function. It doesn't seem to work, any ideas?

Comment: I believe you should post your problem with the custom function as another question, linking it to this one. Comments are not especially convenient to do troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks tonytonov, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23273522/lapply-returns-null-when-using-custom-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23273522/lapply-returns-null-when-using-custom-function)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to put them in a list along the lines of:

```
raw_data <- vector(mode = "list", length = numruns) #allocate space for list
for (i in 1:numruns){ raw_data[[i]] <- read.csv(name[i], header=F, sep="\t", skip=11)}
```

you can use `lapply` do do this in one command instead - might be worth reading up for the future.

The reason that your code isn't working is that you're assigning the string "raw_data_1" to raw_data, and then overwriting it with the data from the file. If you really want to go down the route of having lots of variables, have a look at `assign()` and `get()`.

Comment: Ahh. I think I understand now. I'm still learning but this is very helpful information. Feels very satisfying to reduce that wall of code down to a few lines! I still need more practice to understand lists, etc, hopefully that will come soon.