# lapply returns NULL when using custom function

Tags: r, lapply

I've experienced a similar problem more along the lines of being inefficient rather than than failing to function, it was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247021/read-csv-in-loop-that-gets-filenames) using lapply.

(Edited) 
I'm including working code with junk data this time that will throw the error back when run. The code below works as is, however I would like to replace the if (numruns ==... ) statements with the #'d lapply functions at the very end.
The lapply using func_ign_time assigns NULL values.
I'm also encountering some errors with the func_drop_time, but they may be related.

```
numruns = 3
pyro_1 <- as.numeric(c(100,70,50,2,3,4,60,160,260,360,503))
pyro_2 <- as.numeric(c(100,100,100,70,50,2,3,4,60,160,260,360,503))
pyro_3 <- as.numeric(c(100,100,70,50,2,3,4,60,160,260,360,503))
time_diff <- seq(1,100,1)

func_ign_time <- function(data, delay = 5, threshold = 5, time="time_diff"){
        diff_data <- diff(data[1:length(data)])
        flag <- 0
        for (i in 1:length(diff_data)){
                if (diff_data[i] > threshold && diff_data[i+1] > threshold && i > delay){
                        flag <- 1
                        time <- as.numeric(time_diff[i])
                        #print(paste0("Plug ignition time: ", time, " seconds"))
                        return (time)
                }
        }
}
func_drop_time <- function(data, threshold = -5, time="time_diff"){
        diff_data <- diff(data[1:length(data)])
        flag <- 0
        for (i in 1:length(diff_data)){
                if (diff_data[i] < threshold && flag == 0){
                        flag <- 1
                        time <- as.numeric(time_diff[i])
                        #print(paste0("Plug drop time: ", time, " seconds"))
                        return(time)
                }
        }
}

if (numruns == 3){
        time_ign_3 <- as.numeric(func_ign_time(pyro_3)-func_drop_time(pyro_3))
        time_ign_2 <- as.numeric(func_ign_time(pyro_2)-func_drop_time(pyro_2))
        time_ign_1 <- as.numeric(func_ign_time(pyro_1)-func_drop_time(pyro_1))
        print(paste(time_ign_1,time_ign_2,time_ign_3))
}
if (numruns == 2){
        time_ign_2 <- as.numeric(func_ign_time(pyro_2)-func_drop_time(pyro_2))
        time_ign_1 <- as.numeric(func_ign_time(pyro_1)-func_drop_time(pyro_1))
        print(paste(time_ign_1,time_ign_2))
}
if (numruns == 1){
        time_ign_1 <- as.numeric(func_ign_time(pyro_1)-func_drop_time(pyro_1))
        print(paste(time_ign_1))
}

#ign_names <- paste0("pyro_", seq_len(numruns))
#xx <- lapply(ign_names, function(x) (func_ign_time(x)))
#yy <- lapply(ign_names, function(x) (func_drop_time(x)))
#zz <- xx-yy
```

Comment: The context here is a little unclear; it would help if you could edit your question so that the code can run on its own. Initially, I see that you're using `lapply` to call `func_ing_time`, but the `return` value of `func_ing_time` is nested within a loop. You can only return one value from a function; are you expecting the `func_ing_time` function to return multiple values? If so, then you should replace the `for` loop within the func_ing_time with a call to `lapply` or `sapply`. Again, it would be easier to help you if you posted code that runs.

Comment: In addition to the comment above, please specify the input: what is `pyro_x`, a vector or a data frame? Check out [this guideline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to learn about how to ask a great question.

Comment: Thanks, i've updated the question and hopefully it's more understandable. Pyro_x is a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a char variable to `func_ign_time(...)`, when it expects a vector (apparently). In other words, you're doing the equivalent of:

```
func_ign_time("pyro_1")
```

when you want

```
func_ign_time(pyro_1)
```

Try this instead:

```
lst <- list(pyro_1, pyro_2,pyro_3)
lapply(ign_names, func_ign_time)
```

Alternatively, try:

```
lapply(mget(ign_names), func_ign_time)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This actually works when I use a list with the names pyro_1-3. Unfortunately this dances around the original problem which was to automate the population of a list that contains e.g. pyro_1-3, when numruns ==3, pyro_1-2, when numruns ==2, etc

Comment: `lapply(mget(ign_names)[1:numruns], func_ign_time)`

Comment: Works! I'm sorry I don't completely understand it yet, but I've gotten the return values I believe I want. `(x<-as.numeric(lapply(mget(ign_names)[1:numruns], func_ign_time))`
`y<-as.numeric(lapply(mget(ign_names)[1:numruns], func_drop_time))`
`z<-x-y)`